# No place to put base for a ceiling lamp

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

I recently moved to a new house and there are no ceiling lights. I can only see the wires but no place to put a hook for my fixture. Any idea how should I install my lights?

[image]

Comment: This may help in what not to do : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFuYIi5-igc

Answer (score 2):

I would scrape off the paint in that circle to see what is there - you might find screws etc

If not then I have used a bradawl in the past to find the joist - usually light fittings are close to joists for support or an extra piece of wood is fitted between two joists to provide support.

Comment: in the bathroom there is a lamp. They hang it from that yellow cable. is it safe to hang a fixture from that cable?

Comment: Who knows? I gave you advice on how I would proceed, I can't tell what the yellow cable is, but I,personally, would not use it for hanging a fixture, unless it was specifically designed for that purpose.